# Plotly installation difference from python-plotly and pip install plotly (debian)

Tags: python, plot, debian, pip, plotly

actually I don't know if this is the right place where to ask this question, but maybe someone could help.

I'm exploring the [plotly](https://plot.ly) library through the [python API](https://plot.ly/python/)

Since some months it is possible to use plotly also offline without being registered.

I noticed a difference during the installation of plotly in python

```
1. aptitute python-plotly
2. pip install plotly
```

with the pip installation all works fine.

However, with the python-plotly installation, during the running of some script, there are some issues:

```
[Errno 2] File o directory non esistente:
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/offline/plotly.min.js' See log
for more details
```

and effectively:

```
ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/offline/
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  offline.py  offline.pyc
```

with the pip installation the file is correctly installed and therefore there are not any problems.

I have experienced the same problem on debian stable, testing and unstable machines.

I have already opened an [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/449) on the ploty repository on github

Someone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the github issue linked above, the Debian [and Ubuntu] version doesn't include the minified js file due to licensing issues.

Quick fix, copy the file at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/plotly.js/master/dist/plotly.min.js to the location specified in the error message:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/offline/plotly.min.js
```